# How do I properly add a custom view to an activity

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I'm trying to build a custom view but for some reason it's not displaying at all.

To save you reading both constructors, I am calling the View constructor without the attr parameter because these should be fetched from the Layout file. Any values that are not fetched from here are set in the view class itself.

My view class:

```
package mrl233.campustour.AugmentedReality;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import mrl233.campustour.R;

/**
 * TODO: document your custom view class.
 */
public class CameraOverlay extends View {

    private float mAzimuth;
    private float mPitch;
    private float mRoll;
    private String mTextString;
    private int mTextColor = Color.RED;
    private float mTextDimension = 80;
    private Drawable mTextDrawable;
    private float mTextSize = 29;
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private float mTextHeight = 0;
    private float mTextWidth;


    public CameraOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.CameraOverlay,
                0, 0);

        try {
            mTextString = a.getString(R.styleable.CameraOverlay_exampleString);
            mAzimuth = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CameraOverlay_exampleFloat_X, 0);
            mPitch = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CameraOverlay_exampleFloat_Y, 0);
            mRoll = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CameraOverlay_exampleFloat_Z, 0);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
        init();
    }
    public CameraOverlay(Context con, float azimuth, float pitch, float roll) {
        this(con,null);
        this.mAzimuth = azimuth;
        this.mPitch = pitch;
        this.mRoll = roll;
        TypedArray a = con.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                null,
                R.styleable.CameraOverlay,
                0, 0);

        try {
            mTextString = a.getString(R.styleable.CameraOverlay_exampleString);
            mAzimuth = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CameraOverlay_exampleFloat_X, 0);
            mPitch = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CameraOverlay_exampleFloat_Y, 0);
            mRoll = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CameraOverlay_exampleFloat_Z, 0);

        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
        init();

    }
        @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            invalidate();
            int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
            int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
            int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
            int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();

            int contentWidth = getWidth() - paddingLeft - paddingRight;
            int contentHeight = getHeight() - paddingTop - paddingBottom;

            canvas.drawText("wsfsefseefsfsef",
                    paddingLeft + (contentWidth - mTextWidth),
                    paddingTop + (contentHeight + mTextHeight)
                    ,mTextPaint);


    }

}
```

This is my view layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/overlay"  >

    <mrl233.campustour.AugmentedReality.CameraOverlay
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="300dp" android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp" custom:exampleDimension="24sp" custom:exampleColor="#33b5e5"
        custom:exampleString="Hello, CameraOverlay"
        custom:exampleFloat_X="0.1"
        custom:exampleFloat_Y="0.5"
        custom:exampleFloat_Z="1"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am adding this view to to an activity which has it's own view. This is the Activity class's onCreate method which is where I try to add the view.

```
 @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_augment);

        preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
        mCameraOverlay = new CameraOverlay(this, 0, 0, 0);

        preview.addView(mPreview);
        preview.addView(mCameraOverlay);
        preview.bringChildToFront(mCameraOverlay);

    }
```

The layout of this activity class:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/augment"
        tools:context="mrl233.campustour.Activities.Augment">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--<SurfaceView-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/surfaceView"/>-->

            <mrl233.campustour.AugmentedReality.CameraOverlay
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here. You shouldn't be calling invalidate() in onDraw method cause it causes view to redraw itself(infinite loop). Secondly getWidth() might be 0 there. You might want to get canvas width from onSizeChanged method

```
private int width;
private int height;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    ...
    int contentWidth = width - paddingLeft - paddingRight;
    ...
}
```

try playing with hardcoded sizes cause currently you might be drawing that text offscreen or giving it too little space(it might help you find the problem).
Smallest customView I can Think of would be:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    private TextPaint paint;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new TextPaint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawText("Hello", 20, 20, paint);
    }
}
```

and init it:

```
preview.addView(new CustomView(this));
```

There are few more smaller problems but it might get you going

Comment: When I add that custom view it appeared, I looked into the values being supplied by my onDraw method and you were correct, When I called the drawText method I was giving an x and y argument which was outside the visible  area of my screen. This fixed my issue thanks.

Comment: If you have other input about the small problems that you mentioned in your answer I would be most grateful if you shared why they are problems and how they can be improved?

Comment: just couldn't understand few things why they were there but it was probably cause you were testing things out. Like this separate layout xml isn't actually used in the shown code and camera_preview FrameLayout already contains one CameraOverlay(you are adding one more programatically). And if going deeper then nested layouts are bad for performance specially when they are inside RelativeLayout cause they will be measured twice or if you are using layout_weight(probably you were using LinearLayout there before)(but really a minor impact). Less view nesting is needed in current situation :)